# Why can't Unary Operators operate directly on values in Java?

Tags: java, unary-operator

Not that I want to, but I'm wondering why the unary operators don't work directly on values in Java?

Why does `result++;` work if `int result = 0;` but `result = 0++;` not work?

All I can find in the `docs` is that the unary operator only requires one `operand`, but there is no clear definition for an operand, and it seems that it can be either a variable or a value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not that unary operators don't work - for example -(+(-5)) is fine.

But `++` doesn't just compute a value - its purpose is to increment a variable. 0 isn't a variable.

From [JLS 15.14.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2) (postfix increment operator++)

> The result of the postfix expression must be a variable of a type that is convertible (§5.1.8) to a numeric type, or a compile-time error occurs.

Note that this isn't just about literals, either. You can't do:

```
String x = "foo";
x.length()++; // wrong!
```

because again, `x.length()` isn't classified as a variable.

But you *can* use other unary operators, e.g.

```
String x = "foo";
int y = -x.length(); // Unary - operator... that's fine
```